# How to pre process Pro*C files in cmake?

Tags: c, oracle, cmake, proc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile additional source files in cmake after the build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490096/how-to-compile-additional-source-files-in-cmake-after-the-build-process)

I need to preprocess a proc file (Pro*C oracle) to generate a C file and then compile it along the rest of C files, I've tried to solve it without success like this

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my_proj OUTPUT PRE_LINK
    COMMAND ${PCC} iname=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${conn}.proc 
        SQLCHECK=SYNTAX MODE=ANSI IRECLEN=255 ORECLEN=255
        ONAME=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${conn}.c
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${conn}.c
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14490096/424459  If the answer there doesn't help, it might be better to comment on the answer rather than duplicating your question.